# Is it safe to use Google cloud functions and puppeteer for user code sandbox?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

Currently I use a VM with compilebox to run non secure users code at my app..

I’ve read about puppeteer and google cloud functions at this post: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-headless-chrome-support-in-cloud-functions-and-app-engine

Can I use it as a sandbox environment just like compilebox? Or the environment variables of google cloud will be exposed to the non secure code? Thanks..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your concern.  What situation are you trying to avoid?

Comment: The most common would be the user trying to access process.env variables, for example

Comment: Are you thinking of running the user's JavaScript code inside the Chrome browser console automated by Puppeteer in your GCF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine, Function, Compute Engine and likely others, all provide some built in services for handling things like authentication in client libraries. I don't think you'd want to run user provided code within the same GCP project straight on top of GCP hosting resources. I think your approach to running a sandbox within a VM is safer.